# Django admin Actions - exportascsv snippet not working when added to the whole site, but working when added to individual model 

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to use this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2369/) for exporting the admin models as a CSV file .
It is working fine in this way:

Added the downloaded snippet as actions.py and write below code in the admin.py of any app

```
from actions import export_as_csv_action

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (...)
    list_filter = [...]
    actions = [export_as_csv_action("CSV Export", fields=['field1', 'field2'])]
```

The above method is working but in this method we have to add the action to every model separately . There is another way to add the action to all the models in an app by writing the below code in the admin.py of that app.

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.add_action(export_as_csv_action, "export csv")
```

From the above code, the action "export csv" is being displayed in the admin page, but when I select it and click GO, then nothing is happening, just page is being redirected to the same page, can you please tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Are `export_selected_objects` and `export_as_csv_action`referring to the same export function?  Or are you trying to add `export_as_csv_action` as global action?

Comment: sorry, both are the same . I am editing the question .

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parenthesis in the "export_as_csv_action()" call:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.add_action(export_as_csv_action(), "export csv")
```